# Android Navigation Component remove toolbar animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack

how can i remove toolbar animation when I am using navigation component with toolbar like this:

`NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment))`

Inside each fragment i have custom menu (and `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`). On every fragment transaction made by `findNavController().popBackstack()` toolbar menu items has ugly transition animation. 
If i remove `setupWithNavController`, animation disappers, but i need it.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? These animations look terrible

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution :/

Comment: It's so weird. How can this problem stay unnoticed for so long? For me it's also showing the wrong toolbar title on the first screen until I move back to it once.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out that you don't get these animations if you call `Activity.setupActionBarWithNavController` or `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController` instead of the Toolbar-specific function.

You also have to override `onSupportNavigateUp` to handle the up button if you use this approach:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

And if you use a Toolbar, don't forget to call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` to make the Toolbar your default ActionBar.

Comment: It doesn't work if you use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`  since it calls `setActionBar`

Comment: @Shynline you just have to call `setSupportActionbar(toolbar)` before, no?

Comment: @FlorianWalther This works but clicking on back button the backpress event is not triggered.What can be done?

Comment: calling activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,

Comment: @Rockin You need to override `onSupportNavigateUp` as I show in the edited answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Thanks for edits.Still activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) { override fun handleOnBackPressed() { } Doesnt get called while clicking the nvigateup back button within Fragment. I Use NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment), AppBarConfiguration(setOf( ))) Also setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: I am not sure the `onBackPressDispatcher` should be called when we click up, after all, up is not the back button. Is it called when you use `Toolbar.setUpActionBarWithNavController`?

Comment: @FlorianWalther  Yes its working when using toolbar function but strange animation looks ugly while popping.
The fragment is added to back stack.The button <- is navigating but not calling onBackPressDispatcher niether the hardware back button.If we use toolbar function it gets called.

Comment: @FlorianWalther I just had an investigation.System OnBackPressed is gets called.Android stuid 4.1 has some debugger issue since the debug was not coming using function without toolbar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755617/android-studio-4-1-some-breakpoint-doesnt-trigger

Now upgraded to 4.1.2 the flow works as you said.
NavigationUp to trigger system backpress i added in activity.

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem : MenuItem) : Boolean {
        if (menuItem.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
            return true

Comment: Also I am great fan of coding in flow thanks for the videos in youtube.

Comment: @Rockin Thank you and good to hear that it seems to work now!

Comment: still the case!

behavior differs because extension `toolbar.setupWithNavController` uses `ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener` internally, for listening navigation events, and it does use transition inside, `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` may be found if you check sources.

on the other hand: extension `Activity.setupActionBarWithNavController` uses `ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener` internally, and this implementation does not call any transitions