# Android studio 4.1 some breakpoint doesnt trigger

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Why doesn't some of my breakpoints trigger? I'm not sure when this issue started, but I now have it in more than one project.

I have Android studio 4.1, no newer updates that I can find.

I have updated to Gradle 6.5 with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`
And I have tried downgrading to 4.0.2 and also updating Gradle to 6.7 and other variations. All this without any effect.

[image: This breakpoint triggers]

[image: This breakpoint doesnt trigger]

In the two above images I have breakpoints, they are in the same java file. The first one triggers and stops execution. The second one doesn't trigger and stop execution. I know the the code in the second image runs, because during my tests I added a toast there and that toast was shown when I ran my app.

The app runs as expected, I just cant debug some parts of it.

So now i don't know what else to test! Help and tips are very much appreciated!

**Update:** I tried something weird. I created a new method from inside the method in screenshot 2. If I set a breakpoint in the new method it triggers!!!
I have noticed that the breakpoints that don't trigger don't have the little checkmark in them, I assume that the mean something.
[image: Breakpoint triggered]
So what does this mean, do I need extra methods in all my listeners just to be able to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again when updating to Android Studio 4.1.1 with `Gradle plugin v4.1.1` and `Gradle Version 6.7`
So i guess it was a bug with Android Studio 4.1